# Spring Boot test and overriding the value of a private member

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am writing a spring boot test, but I use the annotation `@Test`

I am able to create a bean that has an annotation `@Autowired`. This bean has a private data member like below

```
    @Value("${producer.enabled}")
    private boolean isEnabled;
```

In my test code, the bean is created like below

```
    @Autowired
    private MyClass mclass;
```

The test class has a test that is like this

```
    @Test
    public void hello() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mclass);
    }
```

How do I change the value of the property of `isEnabled` of MyClass for my tests. Say I write 2 different tests, and I want to use `true` for one test and `false` for another test.